# Remember folder location in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When I upload a file in Chrome, Chrome only remembers the PARENT folder when I continue with a next file. I need to upload dozens of files in the same folder, so this gets very time-consuming.

Example:

I click on BROWSE in a form, go to `/home/user/Desktop` and select a file.
I click on another BROWSE button in a form, and the popup opens in `/home/user`, so I need to go to Desktop manually.

Any idea?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, like George Edison commented, what Chrome are you using. Update Chrome to the latest version in case it was a bug that has been fixed.

Secondly, I tested on various sites and it works fine, remembering the last location I was in for a Browse. I would guess that it's probably the site you're trying to upload to; it's probably coded to go to the parent folder by mistake. Try it out on something like Gmail attachments or another popular site and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Now that I am upgraded to version 14, it all works fine indeed. Thanks for the help!